# Does PEP 0440 allow omitting the separator for development releases?

Tags: python, semantic-versioning, pep

[PEP 0440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) includes the following two statements which seem to be contradictory:

> Development releases allow a `.` , `-` , or a `_` separator as well as omitting the separator all together. The normal form of this is with the `.` separator. This allows versions such as `1.2-dev2` or `1.2dev2` which normalize to `1.2.dev2` .

and

> Note that `devN` and `postN` MUST always be preceded by a dot, even when used immediately following a numeric version (e.g. `1.0.dev456` , `1.0.post1` ).

Is the 2nd statement wrong?  Is it allowed to omit the separator all together?  If so, what is the process for alerting the PEP author to correct the PEP?

Comment: The PEP contains a 'discuss to' link for a mailinglist, that seems like an obvious target to send inquiries to.

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but the second quote is from a section labelled with *This section is intended primarily for authors of tools that automatically process distribution metadata, rather than developers of Python distributions deciding on a versioning scheme.*

Comment: The first part talks about normalisation. So once normalised, the separator should not be dropped again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the suggestions, I have posted to the 'discuss to' mailing list.  I'll update with an answer if/when I hear back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martijn's comment is correct, the 2nd statement is regarding the normalized form.

Donald Stufft confirmed on the distutils-sig@python.org mailer:

> Once normalized it must have a dot. The normalization is applied first.